# Why there is a line on the top of UIImagePickerView?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new here and I may ask my fist stupid question now...:)

I use `UIImagePickerView` to take my photos but strangely there is a white line on the top of the camera...

What i have done is:

1. A new `UIviewController`, and the controller will present a new `UIImagePickerController` in `viewWillAppear` method:

   ```
   UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   imagePicker.delegate = self;
   [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
   ```
2. I add this control into the `UITabController` as one of the item.
3. open my app and click on the tab to show `UIImagePickerView`. Then an unexpected line shown on the top of my camera.

Who can tell why this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We get this too, but not on all phones. IPhone 4 on GSM yes, Verizon no.